# Noun(adjective) or adjective noun with multiple nearly same labels

Tags: forms, input-fields, labels

When desinging labels with items that are nearly the same and only differ in a detail, what's the best approach to name the labels (desktop, not mobile)?

[image: Qualification level and Sought qualification level] 
vs [image: Qualification level and Qualification level (sought)] 
vs [image]

To take a more abstract approach:
If I got multiple related labels with a noun (2, 3 or more items) that can only be distincted with an adjective, which of the following is the most readable design?

```
Noun           [input]
Adjective noun [input]
```

or

```
Noun             [input]
Noun (adjective) [input]
```

or even

```
Noun (as caption)
Adjective1 [input]
Adjective2 [input]
```

Comment: Welcome to UXSE Chriz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would go for the third option:

[image]

As these fields are closely related to each other it makes sense to group them together. This allows you to be more specific- yet simple- with the label copy text, without repeating yourself with redundant text.

---

[Further reading:](https://uxplanet.org/designing-more-efficient-forms-structure-inputs-labels-and-actions-e3a47007114f)

> You should group related information in logical blocks or sets. The flow from one set of questions to the next will better resemble a conversation. Grouping related fields together also helps users make sense of the information that they must fill in. Below is an example for Contact Information.

[image]